# process tag before converting it into tag using bootstrap tags input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

i am using bootstrap tags input in my site.
basically what i am trying to do is,
ask user to type urls into a text field, now if the text is valid url then only convert it into tag otherwise don't.

is there any way to process text before converting into tags?

any help would be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look at `itemValue` and `itemText` - it can be callback http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap tags have **beforeItemAdd** event which triggered just before an item gets added. [Bootstrap tags](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

```
$('input').on('beforeItemAdd', function(event) {
    /* Validate url */
    if (/^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})).?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i.test(event.item)) {
        event.cancel = false;
    } else {
        event.cancel = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man... just exactly i am looking for... here is the working fiddle i created with your help.. https://jsfiddle.net/qr7uumbb/10/

Comment: It's my pleasure:)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Tags Input have a `hidden` input before convert to `tags` you find it by following code:

```
$(".bootstrap-tagsinput input[type="text"]").keyup(function(){
// do your validation
});
```

you can see it by get an `inspect element` in your page. it will convert to `tags` after you press `enter button` you can do your validation until it's on hidden input.

It will be there:

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
<span class="tag label label-info">Test<span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
<input type="text" style="width: 7em;" size="1"> // here is!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input id is "tag-input", all you have to do is use a `beforeItemAdd`callback provided by the library itself like so:

```
$('#tag-input').on('beforeItemAdd', function(event) {
        var tag = event.item;

        if(true){ //if tag is not a url or process other text conditions.
          event.cancel = true
        }
});
```

If you don't set `event.cancel` to false, the `add` will go through.

You can check the documentation on this method [here](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#methods).

Also , as it is clear in this case that documentation does not say how to cancel the event. In such cases its simple enough to just check the code itself. I this case [this code](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js#L130) in the plugins github repo makes it plenty clear how to use this option.